# Pyinstaller says that file already exists, but it doesn't

Tags: python, terminal, exe, pyinstaller

Ok, so I'm trying to make a little python script into an exe file, and I'm using pyinstaller. (My command I'm using is `pyinstaller.exe --windowed --icon=pics\icon.ico -F --onefile main.py`) I've figured out how to use pyinstaller, and it's worked before when I was making earlier versions of this python program. Now it isn't working, and I don't know why. It's saying that a file that it's trying to make already exists, except it doesn't (I've checked), and it's giving me this error:

```
765 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
765 INFO: Python: 3.7.1
765 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyinstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 109, in run
    spec_file = run_makespec(**vars(args))
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 56, in run_makespec
    spec_file = PyInstaller.building.makespec.main(filenames, **opts)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\makespec.py", line 331, in main
    os.makedirs(specpath)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Game Center'
```

(It's done this before, but that time, the file I was trying to make DID exist already. I deleted the file, tried again, and it all worked fine.)
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I don't know what changed, but it works just fine now. I just waited a week and came back to it. I guess God just sent a miracle!